# Photos for each post in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have created a blog website and I want to display images for every post like YouTube thumbnails. I created an image field in my Post Class but it is not saving my image in the media folder when I create a post.

Post class in models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(default='Concert', max_length=100)
    invite = models.ImageField(default='invite.jpg', upload_to='invite_pics')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name    

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

This is my CreatePost class in views.py:

```
class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home_page/post_form.html'
    fields = ['name', 'invite']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I have set the MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

post_form.html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Create New Event</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Post</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

So as I have said earlier, the image is not getting saved to media/invite_pics what should I do?

Comment: How does your template look like? Especially the `<form>` part?

Comment: I have updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to submit data and files, you need to specify the `enctype="…"` parameter of the `form`:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    …
</form>
```